# Convert NSString to NSDate with UTC-5 timezone formatter

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nstimezone

I have this `NSDateFormatter`:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];
```

I have this NSString :

```
NSString *geolocaliser=@"09/11/2014 03:03:20 UTC+1";
```

and I want to convert it to an NSDate object:

```
NSDate *lastLocatedUserDate =[formatter dateFromString:geolocaliser];
```

The output here is perfect: `lastLocatedUserDate=2014-11-09 02:03:20 +0000`

Now if I have this NSString:

```
NSString *geolocaliser=@"11/11/2014 12:07:40 UTC−5" ;
```

I'm getting a null value : `lastLocatedUserDate=(null)`

I'm thinking that the problem is because `UTC-5`, but it's not the same thing as `UTC+1`?

Thank you for helping .

Comment: Does it work if you replace `zzz` with `O` (capital O)? What about if you replace `UTC` with `GMT` in your string?

Comment: @rmaddy: I tried it, and it's the same thing, it gives me a null nsdate value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out to be a very non-obvious issue.

Your string `@"11/11/2014 12:07:40 UTC−5"` has an invalid character in it. The apparent dash in the timezone is actually the Unicode character "MINUS SIGN" (U+2212) instead of a plain old "HYPHEN-MINUS" (U+002D).

Replace the `−` with `-` and your code will work properly.

Comment: I can't say more than "no comment", honestly! I just want to know how did you notice that ?

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into a test app and sure enough, I got `nil` too. Then I edited the timezone string a few times until I typed back in "UTC-5" and it worked. So then I knew your "UTC-5" and mine must be different. So I copied and pasted your "−" into the Unicode viewer and saw what it really was.

Comment: Brother, thank you very much for taking some time to help me!